# Data in 1st row should be equal to the last row- Using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with around 15 columns and all i am trying to do is see if the data in 1st row of partition_num is equal to the data in last row of partition_num if its not equal, add a new row at the end with the data from the 1st row

Input:

```
row   id  partition_num   lat    long    time
 0     1    7333           24     26      9
 1     2    7333           15     19      10
 2     3    7333           24     25      9
 3     1    8999           26     18      15
 4     2    8999           15     17      45
 5     3    8999           26     18      15
 6     1    3455           12     14      18
 7     2    3455           12     14      18
```

Desired output:

```
row   id  partition_num   lat    long    time
 0     1    7333           24     26      9
 1     2    7333           15     19      10
 2     3    7333           25     26      9
 3     4    7333           24     26      9
 4     1    8999           26     18      15
 5     2    8999           15     17      45
 6     3    8999           26     18      15
 7     1    3455           12     14      18
 8     2    3455           12     14      18
```

Since the data for partition_num -7333 in row 0 is not equal to the data in row 2, add a new row(row 3) with same data as row 0

can we add a new column to identify the new record something like flag :

```
row   id  partition_num   lat    long    time   flag  
 0     1    7333           24     26      9      old  
 1     2    7333           15     19      10     old  
 2     3    7333           25     26      9      old  
 3     4    7333           24     26      9      new  
 4     1    8999           26     18      15     old  
 5     2    8999           15     17      45     old  
 6     3    8999           26     18      15     old  
 7     1    3455           12     14      18     old  
 8     2    3455           12     14      18     old
```

Comment: how does row3(2) changes in output?  in the input is same as row 1

Comment: Row number is automatically populated in postgres, i am only concerned about adding a new row with additional id if the 1st row in partition_num is not equal to last row in the same partition_num

Comment: what i meant is if you see the row 3 it is same to row 1(in the input), which defies your logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupby` will easily build sub_dataframes per `partition_num`. From that point the processing is simple:

```
for i, x in df.groupby('partition_num'):
    if (x.iloc[0]['partition_num':] != x.iloc[-1]['partition_num':]).any():
        s = x.iloc[0].copy()
        s.id = x.iloc[-1].id + 1
        df = df.append(s).reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis('row')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code compares the values of `'partition_num'` in the first and last row, and if they don't match, appends the first row onto the end of the data frame:

```
if df.loc[0, 'partition_num'] != df.loc[len(df)-1, 'partition_num']:
    df = df.append(df.loc[0, :]).reset_index(drop=True)
    df.index.name = 'row'

print(df)
```

```
     id  partition_num  lat  long  time
row                                    
0     1           7333   24    26     9
1     2           7333   15    19    10
2     3           7333   24    26     9
3     1           8999   26    18    15
4     2           8999   15    17    45
5     3           8999   26    18    15
6     1           3455   12    14    18
7     2           3455   12    14    18
8     1           7333   24    26     9
```

The index column is set to 'row', and it is reset and renamed to get the correct ordering.

Comment: Thanks so much Nathaniel for your quick turnaround, Somehow it threw a Type error from my end so i tried the other method and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Added this piece to the above logic:
s['flag']= 'new_row'

and it worked!!